# Javascript external file does not find the right element

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am programming a website using PHP, html and JavaScript. I want to add PHP (and html) content in a div, when clicking an Icon. Due to Content Security Policy I have to use an external file for the JavaScript Code.
I already tried the function in another PHP Project with a button, where it worked.
my relevant PHP Code is:

```
<div id="Target" > </div>

    <div class="task-form-add">

        <i class="task-form-add fa fa-plus-circle " id= "btnadd" ></i>

    </div>
```

with:

```
    <script defer="" type="text/javascript" src="/myFolder/inputTask.js?1557323110"></script>
```

in the header. My Javascript code is:

```
function loadNewTask() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("Target").innerHTML += this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "elements.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

document.getElementById("btnadd").addEventListener("click", loadNewTask);
```

I wanted the Html Elements from the file Elements.php to appear inside the div with the id "Target", when I click the Icon with the id "btnadd".

I changed the javascript to:

```
    function loadNewTask() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("Target").innerHTML += this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "/fftboard/app/Template/task_creation/show_input-task.php", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

    function activateListeners(){
      var elementLoaded = checkElementLoaded();
      if(document.readyState == "complete" && typeof(elementLoaded) != 'undefined' && elementLoaded != null) {
      elementLoaded.addEventListener("click", loadNewTask);
    }
    else{
      window.setTimeout(activateListeners, 200);
    }   
    }

    function checkElementLoaded (){
      var elementLoaded = document.getElementById("btnadd");
      var loaded = false;
      if(typeof(elementLoaded) != 'undefined' && elementLoaded != null)
      {
        return elementLoaded;
       }

       return null;
       }


    activateListeners();
```

because the Icon "btnadd" is also loaded to the page. Now I do not recive any errors but it still does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have  `<script defer="" type="text/javascript" src="/myFolder/inputTask.js?1557323110"></script>` in the beginning of your file.

Can you put it in the end close to the  tag?

The problem is that you are searching an element that is not yet loaded

Comment: I have tried to put it in several different positions, and the error does not occur any more. It still does not work, but I think your suggestion helped a lot. Thank you